# Getting the indexes of an element in a subset

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have an list and a subset of it, and want to find the index of each element in the subset. I have currently tried this code:

```
def convert_toindex(listof_elements, listof_indices):
     for i in range(len(listof_elements)):
          listof_elements[:] = [listof_indices.index(x) for x in listof_elements]
     return listof_elements

list1 = ['lol', 'please', 'help']
list2 = ['help', 'lol', 'please', 'extra']
```

What I want to happen when I do `convert_toindex(list1, list2)` is the output to be `[2, 0, 1]`

However, when I do this I get a `ValueError: '0'` is not in list.

0, however, appears nowhere in either list so I am not sure why this is happening.

Secondly, if I have a list of lists, and I want to do this process all the nested lists inside the big list, would I do something like this?

```
for smalllist in biglist: 
     smalllist[:] = [dict_of_indices[x] for x in smalllist]
```

Where `dict_of_indices` is the dictionary of indices created following the top answer.

Comment: can you give example of what you want

Comment: show listof_elements, listof_indices and what you want return

Comment: Added in edit^^

Comment: From what I understood, your output should be `[1, 2, 0]` instead of `[2, 0, 1]`. Am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that, instead of doing this one times, you're doing it over and over, N times:

```
 for i in range(len(listof_elements)):
      listof_elements[:] = [listof_indices.index(x) for x in listof_elements]
```

The first time through, you replace every value in `listof_elements` with its index in `listof_indices`. So far, so good. In fact, you should be done there.

But then you do it a second time. You look up each of those indices, as if they were values, in `listof_indices`. And some of them aren't there. So you get an error.

You can solve this just by removing the outer loop. You're already done after the first time.

You may be confused because this problem seems to inherently require two loops—but you already do have two loops. The first is the obvious one in the list comprehension, and the second one is the one hidden inside `listof_indices.index`.

---

While we're at it: while this problem *does* require two loops, it *doesn't* require them to be nested.

Instead of looping over `listof_indices` to find each `x`, you can loop over it in advance to build a dictionary:

```
dict_of_indices = {value: index for index, value in enumerate(listof_indices)}
```

And then just do a direct lookup in that dictionary:

```
listof_elements[:] = [dict_of_indices[x] for x in listof_elements]
```

Besides being a whole lot faster (`O(N+M)` time rather than `O(N*M)`), I think this might also easier be to understand, and to debug. The first line may be a bit tricky, but you can easily print out the dict and verify that it's correct. And then the second line is about as trivial as you can get.

Comment: Wow, it was that simple haha. Makes a lot of sense, Thank you!

Comment: Just an additional question: if I have a list of lists, and I want another list of lists, with this action being done to each list within the big list, I would then have to use a for loop right? Something like 
for smalllist in biglist:
    smalllist[:] = [dict_of_indices[x] for x in smalllist]

Comment: @user5145575 Yes, exactly. (Except that isn't producing another list of lists, it's modifying the existing one. Is that what you want, or not?)